# Ubunutu 12.04 Packet loss

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, drivers, packetloss

I have this Ubuntu Server (12.04.2) which sometimes (thrice a day for 5 minutes) it's unreachable through zabbix and SolarWinds Orion. I logged into to Orion server and Zabbix server and did a ping test (ping -n 500 192.168.1.1) and it had 0% loss. But Orion and Zabbix often report that it is unreachable and packet loss of Orion goes above 60% (Zabbix-agent is unreachable for 5 minutes). 
Can anyone tip me with information to track the issue that is causing this? Would be great to know if  anyone had faced such issue how they tracked/fixed it....

Regards!
Maxi!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by determining when the issue occurs. If it's always happening at the same time, maybe it's a script that's kicking in and doing something. Maybe it's a backup job starting.

Zabbix should be able to give you the time, is it a particular time frame this happens? Same time every day?

If yes, go check the logs.

Comment: no this is random. Everyday it is random!

Comment: Nobody has any tips huh?